# Using #define to create an array in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pic, pragma

I have a header file declaring:

```
  #pragma char PORTC   @ 0x07
  #pragma char PORTD   @ 0x08
  #pragma char PORTE   @ 0x09
```

where I access ports on my PIC-processor by writing PORTC.0, PORTC.1...PORTC.7.

I would like to make an array with these ports, and I'm thinking something like this:

```
#define ARRAY { {PORTC.5, PORTD.2, PORDC.0}, {PORTE.1, PORTD.3, PORTC.6}.... }

int main ( void )
{
   *type* somestuff[3][9] = ARRAY;
   ...
}
```

I want to be able to loop though the ports in a simple manner. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: And what happened when you tried that code?

Comment: I didn't, since I don't know what type to make it as

Comment: What would `PORTC.5` refer to, if `PORTC` is a `char` located at address `0x07`?  That syntax would only apply to a `struct` or a `union`.

Comment: I do see for example:
    #pragma bit  VR0     @ VRCON.0
    #pragma bit  VR1     @ VRCON.1, so I guess they would be bits. Although this is from the header file

Answer (score 0):

The pragma is clearly some kind of compiler-specific language extension, but your code looks like it might just work.

This example uses only regular C syntax only as an example to show how this is *normally* done (and clearly won't do anything special with your devices). You should make the obvious substitutions and see if it works.

```
char PORTC_0 = 1;
....
char PORTE_6 = 42;

int main (void)
{
  struct {char port[3];} dev[3][9] = {{{PORTC_5, PORTD_2, PORDC_0},
                                       {PORTE_1, PORTD_3, PORTC_6},
                                       ....},
                                      {...},
                                      ....};
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
           do_stuff (dev[i][j].port[0], dev[i][j].port[1], dev[i][j].port[2]);
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```